# Fixed footer on every page, without the data overlapping the footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, footer

I would like to add a footer for my print pages and it looks like this, the problem is when i try to add position:fix to it the data above still overlaps the footer, and continues to the 2nd page.
[image]

what i want to know is how this data do not overlap the footer and just go to the next page when it reaches the "NOTE:" div btw im using bootstrap

[image]

page footer:

```
 <div class="row" style="font-size:12px;">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div style="width:100%;height:20px;border-top:1px solid #E8E8E8;border-bottom:1px solid #E8E8E8;"><p style="margin-left:10px;">NOTE:</p> </div> 
       <div style="height:100%;width:50%;border-right:1px solid #E8E8E8;float:left;">
         <p style="margin-left:10px;">Recieved by:</p>
         <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $receiver_name; ?></p>
     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
         <p style="text-align:center">Signature over printed name</p>
         <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $receiver_designation; ?></p>
     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
         <p style="text-align:center">Designation</p>
         <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $receiver_office; ?></p>
    <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Office</p>
       <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $row->date_acquired; ?></p>
       <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Date</p>                                                                                                              </div>
    <div style="float:left;width:50%;" ><p style="margin-left:10px;">Recieved from:</p>
       <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;font-weight:bold;"><?php echo $a_name ?></p>
    <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Signature over printed name</p>
       <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $a_designation ?></p>
   <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Designation</p>
       <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $a_office ?></p>
      <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Office</p>
       <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $row->date_acquired; ?></p>
    <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
       <p style="text-align:center">Date</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/h6y4srez/

Comment: Can you create jsfiddle of your code.

Comment: That `div` block is a nightmare..

Comment: i dont know any other way to make it look like that in the top image XD

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h6y4srez/ fiddle

Answer (score 1):

For adding a footer for  print pages as per requirement I save the code on code pen this should help you also make a note that I did this without using Bootstrap.

Just as a suggestion its better to use class instead of In-line style.

```
<td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
```

[Click to view CodePen](http://codepen.io/manaranjan/pen/yJKorO)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is that you need.

```css
.panel-body{
  position:relative;
}
#footer{
  height:200px;
  width:100%;
  border-right:1px solid #E8E8E8;
  float:left;
  position:absolute;
  top:100%;
  left:0;
  background-color:white;
}
#recieved_by{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
#recieved_from{
  float:left;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-wrapper">

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
             
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                      

                                        <div>
                                             <img src="" style="float:left;margin-right:-60px;margin-top:-10px;"><p style="text-align:center;"><b>Republic of </b><br>
                                       
                                                <button id="ttt" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-print" style="float:right;margin-top:-90px;" onclick="window.print();" >
                                <i class="fa fa-print fa-fw"></i>Print
                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                                    <div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                                            <div class="panel panel-default">
                                                            <div class="panel-body">
                                                                <p style="text-align:center;"><b>PROPERTY ACKNOWLEDGEMENT RECEIPT</b></p>
                                                                
                                                                <p style="float:right;margin-bottom:0px;">Control No.&nbsp&nbsp
                                                              
                                                                </p>
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                <div class="col-md-12" >
                                                                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" style="font-size:12px;">
                                                                        <thead>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Quantity</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Unit</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Description</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Unit Value</th>
                                                                                <th style="text-align:center;font-size:12px;">Property No.</th>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </thead>
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>

                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                            <tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr><tr>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsada</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:60px;">dsadsa</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;width:400px;text-align:center;">das</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:80px;">da</td>
                                                                            <td style="font-size:12px;text-align:center;width:120px;">dsa</td>
                                                                            
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                      
                                                                    </table>

                                                       

                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>

<div  id="footer" class="row" style="font-size:12px;">

<div class="col-md-12">
<div style="width:100%;height:20px;border-top:1px solid #E8E8E8;border-bottom:1px solid #E8E8E8;"><p style="margin-left:10px;">NOTE:</p> </div>
                                                                                                                 <div id="recieved_by" >
                                                                                                                    <p >Recieved by:</p>
                                                                                                        
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Signature over printed name</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Designation</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Office</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Date</p>
                                                                                                                 </div>


                                                                                                             <div id="recieved_from" ><p style="margin-left:10px;">Recieved from:</p>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;font-weight:bold;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Signature over printed name</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Designation</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Office</p>
                                                                                                                      <p style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:0px;margin-top:20px;"></p>
                                                                                                                     <div style="height:1px;width:80%;border-top:1px solid black;margin:0px auto;"></div>
                                                                                                                     <p style="text-align:center">Date</p>


                                                                                                             </div>
                                                                                                        </div>
                                                                                                    </div>
                                                                                   </div>
                                                </div>
                                        </div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/polamoros/h6y4srez/2/)

Comment: doesn't work when its time to print pages the data still overlaps the footer :(

Comment: the data should go to the next page if the data reaches the footer